# [__NSCFSet stringByAppendingFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have a pinpad class that scrambles the buttons on it after every entry. The class works perfectly as an individual project, but when adding to a specific project I get a `[__NSCFSet stringByAppendingFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` message. Here is the method that triggers that message:

```
-(void)touchedButtonInCell:(id)sender
{
    // Obtain the current number string entered from the pinpad.
    _pinpadNumber = [_pinpadNumber stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", [sender tag]];

    // Verification of values
    NSLog(@"%i", [sender tag]);
    NSLog(@"%@", _pinpadNumber);

    // Check the entry of the PINPAD_NUMBER_LENGTH character/number
    if ([_pinpadNumber length] >= PINPAD_NUMBER_LENGTH)
    {
        // Trigger delegate method to handle the pin pad number received.
        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(receivedPinPadNumber:)])
        {
            [_delegate receivedPinPadNumber:_pinpadNumber];
        }
        // Reset the contents of the pin pad number string
        _pinpadNumber = @"";
    }

    // Ensure all elements are scrambled for next number entry.
    [self scramblePinpadGridView];
}
```

If I comment the top _pinpadNumber = [_pinpadNumber line, it prints the appropriate value. When I uncomment the line, it only works the first time, and crashes on second button touched.

I have been struggling for this for a bit over two days. I really hope somebody can bring some light into this.

Comment: Have you run it with zombies enabled?

Comment: Also run "Analyze" found under the Product menu and see if it points out some memory issues. Almost for sure _pinpadNumber is not retained, its getting released, and the OS is using that some memory location for a NSSet later.

Comment: Ok, so when running with zombies I get this: *** -[CFString stringByAppendingFormat:]: message sent to deallocated instance. I still don't understand why it would be releasing the string instance. I don't release it anywhere.

Comment: You do not release it, but you forgot to retain it. It's autoreleased. You say it was developed in a project, then moved to another. Was it developed under ARC and then moved to a manually managed memory project?

Comment: Nope, it was not on ARC originally. I have it's property declared as (nonatomic, copy) and it does the same if I change it to retain.

Answer (score 2):

First, build and analyze your code.   Fix any errors identified.

Next, you are probably not using ARC and this line...

```
_pinpadNumber = [_pinpadNumber stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", [sender tag]];
```

... is assigning an autoreleased object to `_pinpadNumber`.  On the first execution, `_pinpadNumber` is likely `nil` (unless you initialized it to, say, `@""` somewhere else -- it might be a valid object.

On the next pass, that autoreleased object has been drained out of the pool and *boom*, your app crashes with the error you see.

You could turn on zombie detection and likely see a zombie message.